# Find profitable bets from historic results

Tags: python, pandas

Each of the lines in my CSV is a possibility of investment that I register on historic, but I would only make the investment if in the existing history (previous lines) the sum of the results is above zero because it is the sum of profitability or loss.

At each line I need to analyze whether the sum of the previous lines that have the same filters as the current one are above zero or not.

So I need to go line by line.

The problem is that I want to parse all possible combinations of filters, but in a CSV like my complete one that has 48K lines, this becomes a process that takes a long time:

```python
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = df[df['result'].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True)

options = [
    'country',
    'competition',
    'market_name',
    'runner_name',
    'odds'
]

def combs(a):
    if len(a) == 0:
        return [[]]
    cs = []
    for c in combs(a[1:]):
        cs += [c, c+[a[0]]]
    return cs

def my_func(cb, i):
    dfilter = df[:i]
    filter = dfilter[reduce(lambda x, y : x & (df[y[0]] == y[1]), zip(cb, map(lambda x: df.iloc[i][x], cb)), True)]
    back_sum = filter['back'].sum()
    aaa = True
    if back_sum <= 0:
        aaa = False

    return aaa

combinations = combs(options)
combinations = [x for x in combinations if x != []]

for number, cbnt in enumerate(combinations):

    df['invest'] = [my_func(cbnt,i) for i in range(len(df))]
    true_backs = df[(df['invest'] == True)]['back']
    if (true_backs.sum() > 0):
        values = np.cumsum(true_backs)
        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.plot(values)
        fig.savefig(f'C:/Users/Computador/Desktop/Testes VSCODE/figs/{cbnt}.png', dpi=fig.dpi)
        fig.clf()
        plt.close('all')
        print(
            f'{true_backs.sum():.2f}',
            '→',
            len(true_backs),
            cbnt
        )
```

CSV basic Example:

```
clock_now,country,competition,match_id,match_name,market_id,market_name,runner_id,runner_name,total_matched,one,minute_traded,odds,result,back,lay
2022/05/22 12:16,GB,English Premier League,31459682,Brighton v West Ham,1.199215861,First Half Goals 0.5,5851483,Over 0.5 Goals,2692.37,['149.12'♫§ '7.039999999999964'♫§ '48.190000000000055'♫§ '24.08999999999992'♫§ '75.65000000000009'],1797.9199999999998,1.7,WINNER,0.6545,-1
2022/05/22 12:20,HU,Hungarian NB II,31473686,Vasas v Soroksar,1.199438855,Over/Under 6.5 Goals,2542448,Under 6.5 Goals,5801.98,['125.76'♫§ '150.4699999999998'♫§ '200.79'♫§ '51.43000000000029'♫§ '478.25999999999976'],3011.07,1.01,WINNER,0.00935000000000001,-1
2022/05/22 12:21,LU,Luxembourg Division Nationale,31473752,FC Differdange 03 v Progres Niedercorn,1.199439863,Over/Under 0.5 Goals,5851483,Over 0.5 Goals,4451.85,['0.0'♫§ '12.889999999999873'♫§ '22.44000000000005'♫§ '1.2899999999999636'♫§ '219.71000000000004'],1038.0600000000004,1.71,WINNER,0.66385,-1
2022/05/22 12:44,CZ,Czech 1 Liga,31469631,Bohemians 1905 v SFC Opava,1.199387047,Over/Under 2.5 Goals,47972,Under 2.5 Goals,3367.67,['0.0'♫§ '12.950000000000044'♫§ '79.49999999999977'♫§ '103.8100000000004'♫§ '27.94999999999981'],1120.71,1.41,WINNER,0.38334999999999997,-1
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Specifically, _why_ does it matter what the sum of previous lines is?  What does that represent in your problem domain?

Comment: Hi @TobySpeight Because each of the lines is a possibility of investment that I register, but I would only make the investment if in the existing history (previous lines) the sum of the results is above zero because it is the sum of profitability or loss.

Comment: @TobySpeight I modified the question title to explain what the code does

Comment: I've retitled to show the _purpose_ rather than the mechanism.  Check that I've got that correct.